# Rails - 'uninitialized constant' when using a model in ActionMailer interceptor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

I'm writing a small mechanism to handle email bounces and complaints.
I'm basically following a [blog post](http://www.downrightlies.net/posts/2015/05/19/setting-up-ses-on-aws-to-send-emails-from-rails.html) explaining how to implement such a mechanism.

I'm creating and registering an ActionMailer interceptor to make sure that the emails I'm about to send aren't marked as bounced or complained in a model/table I have in my application.

```
# In config/initializers/invalid_email_interceptor.rb

class InvalidEmailInterceptor
  def self.delivering_email(message)
    if EmailResponse.exists? email: message.to
      message.perform_deliveries = false
    end
  end
end

ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(InvalidEmailInterceptor)
```

When I try to send an email, I get the following error:

> uninitialized constant InvalidEmailInterceptor::EmailResponse

It seems my app is looking for EmailResponse in the InvalidEmailInterceptor class instead of my app's models.

I tried playing around with different variations on

```
MyApp::EmailResponse
```

and

```
require 'email_response'
```

but I still get the same error, or can't even start the server.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Simon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally sure, but a way I'd work around is:

1. Check your `app/models/email_response.rb` to ensure that the model is defined. Note: `email_response` not `email_responses`
2. If it is, then you should try: `::EmailResponse`, although I know your models should be available in your initializers.

Comment: It was **email_respnse.rb** (missing the o)... I feel silly.
Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't beat myself up over that. It could happen to anyone. Glad I could help